# Upgrading from Craft 3.7.1 to 3.7.19

Tags: craft3, manual-updates

I've been working through my long overdue updates.
I'm now trying to go from 3.7.1 to 3.7.19
(note: I stop at increments that the CP Update list shows an "update warning triangle").

The composer update worked fine, but the migration failed, here's the migrations that were to be executed:

*Checking for pending migrations ...

- Total 1 new Craft migration to be applied:

  ```
  - m210829_000000_element_index_tweak
  ```
- Total 3 new Social migrations to be applied:

  ```
  - m190304_031715_soft_delete_users
  - m190518_014619_soft_delete_users_fix
  - m190519_185640_soft_delete_login_accounts
  ```

The last migration `m190519_185640_soft_delete_login_accounts` failed, Here's the error:

> *** applying m190519_185640_soft_delete_login_accounts
> Exception: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "userelements"
> LINE 5: WHERE userElements.dateDeleted IS NOT NULL
> ^
> The SQL being executed was: SELECT "social_login_accounts"."id", "social_login_accounts"."userId"
> FROM "social_login_accounts" "social_login_accounts"
> LEFT JOIN "elements" "userElements" ON "userElements"."id" = "social_login_accounts"."userId"
> LEFT JOIN "elements" "loginAccountElements" ON "loginAccountElements"."id" = "social_login_accounts"."userId"
> WHERE userElements.dateDeleted IS NOT NULL (/home/forge/www.site.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:676)

It appears the table, userelements is missing?

How do I move forward?  THANK YOU!

Comment: May be best to reach out to the plugin developer (Craft Social I presume?)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your insights I was able to track down the issue; the `m190519_185640_soft_delete_login_accounts` file had a bug in it.

On line #28: `->where('userElements.dateDeleted IS NOT NULL')`

I changed it to read: `->where('[[userElements.dateDeleted]] IS NOT NULL')`

The rest of the query looks proper, just this one was missed.  The github for this plugin hasn't changed since March of 2022 and I didn't see any issues reported for this migration (although there should have been one) ;-)

After making the change, I re-ran the migration and was able to progress forward.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the [Social plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/social?craft3) you have installed. My guess it's a bug in one of their migrations that doesn't account for case-sensitive database collations and the fix would be to change:

```
WHERE userElements.dateDeleted
```

to:

```
WHERE "userElements"."dateDeleted"
```

Either way, I'd suggest opening an issue on their repo, so they can investigate further:  https://github.com/dukt/social/issues/

Comment: Thank you! I am really grateful for your response. It's weird that it didn't show up in composer update --dry-run.

Comment: Probably because composer's `--dry-run` doesn't know about Craft's migrations, which is where the error is happening.